# textfield count show previous character after deleting character using keyboard in swift 4

Tags: swift4.2

I have used textfield. I need to count the character to call a functions after 11 characters. functions is working find.But when i deleted one character, it shows previous character. I have enter **01921687433** in textfield. But when delete one characters from that number like **0192168743** it shows full number 11 digits not showing 10 digits. But textfield it shows **0192168743**. here is my code..

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
//print("While entering the characters this method gets called")


     let currentText = textField.text! + string

    if(currentText.characters.count == 11){

        print("account 11 digit =", currentText)
      //Action here

    }


  return true;
 }
```

Please help me to find current text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the wrong code for determining the updated text. Keep in mind that any amount of text can be removed, replaced, or added and it can happen anywhere in the string based on the current selection.

Your code should look like this:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let newText = textField.text!.replacingCharacters(in: Range(range, in: textField.text!)!, with: string)

    if newText.count == 11 {
        print("account 11 digit = \(newText)")
    }

    return true
}
```

The force-unwraps in this code are safe. The `text` property of `UITextField` can never return `nil` and the range conversion will always succeed unless Apple introduces a bug in UIKit.

Also note that the use of `characters` has been deprecated for a while. And Swift does not need semicolons at the end of lines nor does it need parentheses in `if` statements.